# Custom XSD simple type to accept date or dateTime

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have an XML element

`<ManufactureDate>20150316</ManufactureDate>`

that uses a custom date type element,

```
<xs:simpleType name="CustomDate">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:maxLength value="8"/>
       <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
       <xs:pattern value="\d*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
/xs:simpleType>
```

for validation, but now I want another element to have the same `CustomDate` datatype but to give an input with time like below

```
<ExpirationDate>20150316T15:53:00</ExpirationDate>
```

Does anyone know how I can change the `simpleType` to accept both types of formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the replies. I could solve this by changing the pattern.

I just used `<xs:pattern value="(\d*)|(\d*T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})"/>` to make it work.

it just didn't work for me before since I had missed the parenthesis earlier.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to create another `simpleType` for custom date that comes with time based on your `CustomDate` type definition :

```
<xs:simpleType name="CustomDateTime">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:maxLength value="17"/>
       <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
       <xs:pattern value="\d*T\d\d:\d\d:\d\d"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

then you can use [`xs:union`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#UnionDt) to accept both of the custom types, like so :

```
<xs:simpleType name="CustomDateOrDateTime">
     <xs:union memberTypes="CustomDate CustomDateTime"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

There are several other routes you can take, f.e change the regex pattern to accept both date with time and without time. Though, I don't know the exact requirement, i.e whether changing `maxLength` restriction acceptable or not, etc.

Comment: Using `xs:union` makes it easy to continue to use both types separately, so prefer this solution, but [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30678400/290085) the single regexp approach that @har07 mentioned too.

Answer (score 1):

I like @har07's idea to use `xs:union`, but if you really want to modify your existing `CustomDate` directly to accept an optional time component, you could use this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="CustomDate">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
    <xs:pattern value="\d{8}(T\d\d(:\d\d){2})?"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Be aware that these regexp-based constraints only lexically approximate date and time datatypes.  For example, where `xs:date` would prohibit months greater than 12, these patterns would accept them.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the solution proposed by @har07, I will propose the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xml:lang="DA">
  <xs:element name="myDateTime" type="CustomDateTime" />
  <xs:simpleType name="DateType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:date" >
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="DateTimeType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime" >
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="CustomDateTime">
    <xs:union memberTypes="DateType DateTimeType"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

It uses the standard XSD date and dateTime formats, which I suspect would be the most standard thing to do rather than to invent a new format. I even think this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xml:lang="DA">
  <xs:element name="SlutDato" type="CustomDateTime" />
  <xs:simpleType name="CustomDateTime">
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:dateTime xs:date"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```